# Floats change behavior when using package "algorithm"

Tags: floats, positioning, algorithms, incompatibility

Not really a problem, but I noticed this when pruning stuff from a document preamble to find a problem I was having. I've found the problem but also something a bit weird

Just the act of importing the package `algorithm` is changing the position of floats (I've tested tables and figures)

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \caption{I'm here}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

If I comment the `\usepackage{algorithm}` line, the caption moves from the top of the page to the middle

Would there be conflicts between definitions or something? Is it normal/acceptable for this to happen?

I've tested this with `pdflatex` and `xelatex` and it behaves the same way

Comment: Without `algorithm` (or some other package such as `float`, which I think `algorithm` loads internally) you don't have access to the `H` placement specifier which removes flotation. From LaTeX2015 on your code without loading `algorithm` throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) uses the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) which defines a `H` float specifier. Without loading `algorithm`, your

```
\begin{table}[H]
  ...
\end{table}
```

actually produces an error stating "Unknown float option `H`".

LaTeX does recover from this error though and then defaults to something different, which changes the display to a page-of-floats-like layout (which has the float centred vertically).

Comment: The error only appears using the kernel's 2015 version. Before, there was no error and not even a warning which is why the OP was surprised.

Comment: Yes, I'm not seeing any errors or warnings. Should I update LaTeX?

Comment: @gsmafra: It's good to live in the present. Either way, the output differs based on the (non-)existing of the float specifier `H`. The most recent release of LaTeX includes (by default) [`fixltx2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e), which updated `\@xfloat` - a macro responsible for throwing errors based on unknown float options (in addition to other things as well).

Comment: Python 3 was released in 2008 and people still use 2.7 to avoid compatibility issues. It could be a dumb comparison, I don't really know what changes from one version to another in LaTeX